# Suma de todos los valores de un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Quiero hacer el siguiente programa: **Web que pida al usuario sus notas y calcule la nota media del trimestre**

**Para hacerlo pensé almacenar todas las notas en un array, mostrarlas por pantalla y después mostrar la media.**

```
var contadorNotas = parseInt(prompt("Introduce cuantos controles has hecho este trimestre:", 0)); // para saber el numero de prompts que han de salir
var controles = new Array(contadorNotas);
for(var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++){
    controles[i] = parseInt(prompt("Introduce las notas"));
}
document.write("<h2>Estas son tus notas:</h2>");
document.write("<ul>")
for(var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++){
    document.write("<li>"+controles[i]+"</li>");
}
document.write("</ul>");
```

Ese es mi código, me gustaría saber como **obtener la suma de los numeros del array** para después **calcular la media**.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```js
var contadorNotas = parseInt(prompt("Introduce cuantos controles has hecho este trimestre:", 0)); // para saber el numero de prompts que han de salir
var controles = new Array(contadorNotas);
for(var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++){
    controles[i] = parseInt(prompt("Introduce las notas"));
}
document.write("<h2>Estas son tus notas:</h2>");
document.write("<ul>")
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++){
    document.write("<li>"+controles[i]+"</li>");
    total += controles[i];
}
document.write("</ul>");
document.write("<h2>Tu promedio es: " + (total / contadorNotas)  + "</h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contadorNotas = parseInt(prompt("Introduce cuantos controles has hecho este trimestre:", 0)); // para saber el numero de prompts que han de salir
var controles = new Array(contadorNotas);
var promedio = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++) {
  controles[i] = parseInt(prompt("Introduce las notas"));
}
document.write("<h2>Estas son tus notas:</h2>");
document.write("<ul>")
for (var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++) {
  document.write("<li>" + controles[i] + "</li>");
}

for (var i = 0; i <= contadorNotas - 1; i++) {
  promedio += controles[i];
  if (i + 1 == contadorNotas) {
    var prom = promedio / contadorNotas;
    document.write("<li>" + "El promedio es :" + prom + "</li>");

  }

}
```

Comment: Tambien es menos eficiente porque no hay necesidad del segundo for loop